# paginación en wordpress muestra mismo contenido en todas las paginas

Tags: wordpress

Saludos amigos esta es mi primera pregunta, manejo una web de alquiler de propiedades. La paginación no me funciona en los custom post type si paso a la pagina 2 me muestra el mismo contenido. Por ejemplo en esta página:

https://www.lafincaquindio.com/fincas-servicios/agua-caliente/

Agradezco su colaboración soy muy nuevo en temas de programación.

Este es el código que controla ese loop en particular:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template with loop of the properties archive
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage ThemeREX Addons
 * @since v1.6.22
 */
 
// Check if meta value exists and update it
$args = array(
 'post_type'=> TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT,
 'posts_per_page' => -1
);  
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()){
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
  $query->the_post(); 
  $post_id = get_the_ID(); 
  $properties = array('trx_addons_properties_area',
  'trx_addons_properties_price',
  'trx_addons_properties_bathrooms',
  'trx_addons_properties_area_size',
  'trx_addons_properties_id',
  'trx_addons_properties_status',
  'trx_addons_properties_address',
  'trx_addons_properties_labels',
  'trx_addons_properties_agent',
  'trx_addons_properties_garages',
  'trx_addons_properties_zip',
  'trx_addons_properties_bedrooms');
  foreach($properties as $item){   
   if(!metadata_exists(TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT, $post_id, $item)){
    add_post_meta($post_id, $item, 0, true);
   }   
   if(empty(get_post_meta($post_id, $item, true))){
    update_post_meta($post_id, $item, 0);
   } 
  }
  if(!metadata_exists(TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT, $post_id, 'trx_addons_properties_title') || empty(get_post_meta($post_id, 'trx_addons_properties_title', true))){
   update_post_meta($post_id, 'trx_addons_properties_title', get_the_title());
  }
 }
}
wp_reset_query();

$query = '';
$args = get_query_var('trx_addons_args_properties_loop');

$trx_addons_need_reset_query = false;
if (!empty($args['query_params'])) {
 $query_args = trx_addons_cpt_properties_query_params_to_args($args['query_params'], true);
 if (count($query_args) > 0) query_posts($query_args);
 $trx_addons_need_reset_query = true;
} else {
 $args = array(
  'post_type'=> TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT,
  'posts_per_page' => -1
    );  
 $args = trx_addons_cpt_properties_query_params_to_args();
 $args['post_type'] = TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT;
 query_posts($args);
 $trx_addons_need_reset_query = true;
}

do_action('trx_addons_action_start_archive');

if (have_posts()) {

 $trx_addons_properties_style   = explode('_', !empty($args['blog_style'])
               ? $args['blog_style']
               : trx_addons_get_option('properties_blog_style')
           );
 $trx_addons_properties_type    = $trx_addons_properties_style[0];
 $trx_addons_properties_columns = empty($trx_addons_properties_style[1]) ? 1 : max(1, $trx_addons_properties_style[1]);

 ?><div class="sc_properties sc_properties_default">
  
  <div class="sc_properties_columns_wrap sc_properties_columns_<?php
   echo esc_attr($trx_addons_properties_columns);
   if ($trx_addons_properties_columns > 1) echo ' ' . esc_attr(trx_addons_get_columns_wrap_class()) . ' columns_padding_bottom';
  ?>"><?php

   while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 
    trx_addons_get_template_part(array(
            TRX_ADDONS_PLUGIN_CPT . 'properties/tpl.properties.'.trim($trx_addons_properties_type).'-item.php',
            TRX_ADDONS_PLUGIN_CPT . 'properties/tpl.properties.default-item.php'
            ),
            'trx_addons_args_sc_properties',
            array(
             'type' => $trx_addons_properties_type,
             'columns' => $trx_addons_properties_columns,
             'slider' => false
            )
           );
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();

  ?></div><!-- .sc_properties_columns_wrap --><?php

    ?></div><!-- .sc_properties --><?php

 the_posts_pagination( array(
  'mid_size'  => 2,
  'prev_text' => esc_html__( '<', 'trx_addons' ),
  'next_text' => esc_html__( '>', 'trx_addons' ),
  'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Page', 'trx_addons' ) . ' </span>',
 ) );

} else {

 trx_addons_get_template_part('templates/tpl.posts-none.php');

}

do_action('trx_addons_action_end_archive');

if ($trx_addons_need_reset_query) wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

dentro del array de parametros, deberías añadir el parametro que he puesto en último lugar.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> TRX_ADDONS_CPT_PROPERTIES_PT,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```